# Can I create custom validation annotation that inherits from javax.constrains annotations

Tags: java, spring, validation

I'm wondering if it's possible to do something like:

```
@Min(1)
@Max(100)
public @interface ValidationForX {}
```

and then

```
@ValidationForX
int X;
```

For some reason `@Min` and `@Max` are applicable on annotations so I'm assuming it should be possible

I want to hide this validation behind one annotation because I want to reuse it

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You annotation must look like this:

```
@Min(1)
@Max(100)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
public @interface ValidationForX {

    String message() default "value should be greater or equal than 1 and less or equal than 100.";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Read more about composing constraints here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-bean-validation-constraint-composition

Comment: It's working as expected, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use @Min and @Max annotation on top of the field which you want to validate.
Something like this:

```
@Max(value=100)
@Min(value=1)
int X;
```

Comment: Yes but if I want to reuse it I'll need to always put this two annotations (or more in my real case)

Comment: I am sorry that should not be done . You should always do validation for a single field
You can reduce these two annotations to one by using below annotation

`@Range(min=1, max=100)`

or you can  create a ConstraintValidator